# Javascript + regex badword filter that ignores whitespace and other characters within the word

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

Well, I thought this would be simple but I am having problems converting some PHP regex code to javascript.

Here is my JS code:

```
for(var i=0; i < badwords.length; i++) {
    var badword = badwords[i].slice(0, -2);
    var regex = "/(";

    for(var j=0; j < badword.length; j++) {
        regex += "[" + badword[j].toLowerCase() + "|" + badword[j].toUpperCase() + "][/W]*";
    }
    regex += ")/";

    msg = msg.replace(new RegExp(regex, "g"), "");
}
```

I am not getting a match and no replacement is happening.  This same code structure and regex format worked in a PHP application.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You don't need `'/'` delimiters in JavaScript when using the `RegExp` constructor.  Furthermore, it is not clear to me what you want to achieve.  You turn `"foo"` into `"/([f|F][/W]*[o|O][/W]*[o|O][/W]*)/"`?  With `[]`, you don't need `|` to specify alternatives (you are matching literal `|` characters instead).  `[/W]` matches `/` or `W`, did you mean `\W` (non-word character) instead?

Comment: I am trying to create a curse word filter.  It was not working because of the [/W] which is now working after I changed the slash, [\W].  Regex is all new to me and I found this while browsing the web.  Any suggestions for a better curse word regex?

Comment: So if `foo` is a bad word then so are `fo o`, `fo,o`, `fo    oooo`, `FoO`, `f.O.O` and `foobar`?

Comment: yes, with the list of curse words that I have, this is what I was aiming for, spaces or other characters in between would not matter and the word would still get matched.

Comment: -1 for the fundamentally stupid concept. So if your bad words list contains "ass", then you would want "classic" to become "cl****ic", and "He has seen the light" to become "He h****een the light"???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input is `foo`, your regular expression should be `/f[^a-z]*o[^a-z]*o/ig`. You can build this regular expression using strings and regular expressions like this:

```
var message = 'this string should not contain "foo", "b a r", "b.l.a.h" and "b_a_z". Baaz is acceptable.';
var badwords = ["foo", "bar", "blah", "baz"];
for (var i = 0; i < badwords.length; i++) {
    var pat = badwords[i].slice(0, -1).replace(/([a-z])/g, "$1[^a-z]*") + badwords[i].slice(-1);
    var rxp = new RegExp(pat, "ig");
    message = message.replace(rxp, "****");
}
message;
// output:
// this string should not contain "****", "****", "****" and "****". Baaz is acceptable.
```

Comment: @Ian: [This](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-.aspx) [is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medireview) [depressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem). Apparently, bigots never learn. Shiiiiiit! (Hey, passes your filter. Yay.)

Comment: Yeah, well I could come up with a more sophisticated badword filter, but the client set the rules for this filter and not me so that is that.  Thanks for everyone's help.